# In C, a cURL call anywhere, even when not executed, crashes the service

Tags: c, windows, curl, service

I am building a small windows service which uses cURL for a small web call.

I can link cURL without issue, but if any `curl_*` functions are in the code - even if none are ever called - the code crashes:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ff8bb75f9f8 in StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
```

Here is the offending function - commenting out just the lines calling `curl_*` functions stops the issue:

```
void phone_home(identity id, char* agent_filename, char* action)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    char service_url[MAX_PATH_LEN], username[MAX_PATH_LEN];

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    get_username(username, MAX_PATH_LEN);
    sprintf(service_url, "%s/%s?identity=%lu&user=%s&agent=%s", LISTENER_HOST, action, id, username, agent_filename);

    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, service_url);

        #ifdef SKIP_PEER_VERIFICATION
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        #endif
         
        #ifdef SKIP_HOSTNAME_VERIFICATION
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
        #endif

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* Check for errors */ 
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* always cleanup */ 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

And here is the `SvcInit` function that never calls that function!

```
VOID SvcInit( DWORD dwArgc, LPTSTR *lpszArgv)
{
    int id;
    identity last_id = 0;
    
    ghSvcStopEvent = CreateEvent(
        NULL,    /* default security attributes */
        TRUE,    /*  manual reset event */
    FALSE,   /* not signaled */
    NULL);   /* no name */

if ( ghSvcStopEvent == NULL)
{
    ReportSvcStatus( SERVICE_STOPPED, NO_ERROR, 0 );
    return;
}

ReportSvcStatus( SERVICE_RUNNING, NO_ERROR, 0 );
while(1)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(ghSvcStopEvent, INFINITE);
    ReportSvcStatus( SERVICE_STOPPED, NO_ERROR, 0 );

    if ((id = scan_for_devices())) {
        if (id != last_id) {
            last_id = id;
            printf("Found marked device 0x%lX!\n", id);
            //phone_home(id, "", ACTION_USBINSERT);
        }
    } else {
        last_id = 0;
    }
    
    Sleep(5000);
}
```

}

And the rest of the service definition code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#include "include/identities.h"
#include "include/identity_agent.h"

#define SVCNAME TEXT("Test")
#define SVCSHOW TEXT("Test Agent")
#define SVCDESC TEXT("Test")

SERVICE_STATUS          gSvcStatus; 
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE   gSvcStatusHandle; 
HANDLE                  ghSvcStopEvent = NULL;

VOID WINAPI SvcCtrlHandler( DWORD ); 
VOID WINAPI SvcMain( DWORD, LPTSTR * ); 

VOID ReportSvcStatus( DWORD, DWORD, DWORD );
VOID SvcInit( DWORD, LPTSTR * ); 
VOID SvcReportEvent( LPTSTR );

int __cdecl _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) 
{
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY DispatchTable[] = 
    { 
        { SVCNAME, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION) SvcMain }, 
        { NULL, NULL } 
    }; 
 
    if (!StartServiceCtrlDispatcher( DispatchTable )) 
    { 
        SvcReportEvent(TEXT("StartServiceCtrlDispatcher")); 
    }

    return 0;
} 

VOID WINAPI SvcMain( DWORD dwArgc, LPTSTR *lpszArgv )
{
    /* Register the handler function for the service */
    gSvcStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler( 
        SVCNAME, 
        SvcCtrlHandler);

    if( !gSvcStatusHandle )
    { 
        SvcReportEvent(TEXT("RegisterServiceCtrlHandler")); 
        return; 
    } 

    gSvcStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS; 
    gSvcStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;    

    ReportSvcStatus( SERVICE_START_PENDING, NO_ERROR, 3000 );

    SvcInit( dwArgc, lpszArgv );
}

VOID SvcInit( DWORD dwArgc, LPTSTR *lpszArgv)
{
    int id;
    identity last_id = 0;
    
    ghSvcStopEvent = CreateEvent(
        NULL,    /* default security attributes */
        TRUE,    /* manual reset event */
        FALSE,   /* not signaled */
        NULL);   /* no name */

    if ( ghSvcStopEvent == NULL)
    {
        ReportSvcStatus( SERVICE_STOPPED, NO_ERROR, 0 );
        return;
    }

    ReportSvcStatus( SERVICE_RUNNING, NO_ERROR, 0 );
    while(1)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(ghSvcStopEvent, INFINITE);
        ReportSvcStatus( SERVICE_STOPPED, NO_ERROR, 0 );

        if ((id = scan_for_devices())) {
            if (id != last_id) {
                last_id = id;
                printf("Found marked device 0x%lX!\n", id);
                //phone_home(id, "", ACTION_USBINSERT);
            }
        } else {
            last_id = 0;
        }
        
        Sleep(5000);
    }
}

VOID ReportSvcStatus( DWORD dwCurrentState,
                      DWORD dwWin32ExitCode,
                      DWORD dwWaitHint)
{
    static DWORD dwCheckPoint = 1;

    /* Fill in the SERVICE_STATUS structure. */
    gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState = dwCurrentState;
    gSvcStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = dwWin32ExitCode;
    gSvcStatus.dwWaitHint = dwWaitHint;

    if (dwCurrentState == SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        gSvcStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
    else gSvcStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP;

    if ( (dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING) ||
           (dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOPPED) )
        gSvcStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
    else gSvcStatus.dwCheckPoint = dwCheckPoint++;

    /* Report the status of the service to the SCM. */
    SetServiceStatus( gSvcStatusHandle, &gSvcStatus );
}

VOID WINAPI SvcCtrlHandler( DWORD dwCtrl )
{
   /* Handle the requested control code. */
   switch(dwCtrl) 
   {  
      case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP: 
         ReportSvcStatus(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING, NO_ERROR, 0);

         /* Signal the service to stop. */
         SetEvent(ghSvcStopEvent);
         ReportSvcStatus(gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState, NO_ERROR, 0);
         
         return;
 
      case SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE: 
         break; 
 
      default: 
         break;
   } 
   
}

VOID SvcReportEvent(LPTSTR szFunction) 
{ 
    HANDLE hEventSource;
    LPCTSTR lpszStrings[2];
    TCHAR Buffer[80];

    hEventSource = RegisterEventSource(NULL, SVCNAME);

    if( NULL != hEventSource )
    {
        StringCchPrintf(Buffer, 80, TEXT("%s failed with %d"), szFunction, GetLastError());

        lpszStrings[0] = SVCNAME;
        lpszStrings[1] = Buffer;

        ReportEvent(hEventSource,        
                    EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, /* event type */
                    0,                   /* event category */
                    /*SVC_ERROR*/0,           /* event identifier */
                    NULL,                /* no security identifier */
                    2,                   /* size of lpszStrings array */
                    0,                   /* no binary data */
                    lpszStrings,         /* array of strings */
                    NULL);               /* no binary data */

        DeregisterEventSource(hEventSource);
    }
}
```

I am compiling with `gcc -o bin/identity_service identity_agent.c identities.c -lcurl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I had not linked cURL statically, so it was looking for the cURL DLLs - which were in the mingw bin directory.... which was in my USER's path....... which services running under system cannot see

I linked curl statically with -DCURL_STATICLIB and all is right with the world